# Compute $\lim_{x\to\infty}x\;\left[\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x-e\right]$

Tags: calculus, limits

How can I compute the following limit, and is there a general method to resolve problems of this type?

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}x\left[\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x-e\right]$$

Comment: $(+\infty)^2 =+\infty$

Comment: I think inside need to be $x[(1+1/x)^x-e]$

Comment: I agree, but we cannot also try to interpret what he wants to ask

Comment: @studentforever You  may be right as $$(x+\frac{1}{x})^x=e^{x(log(x(1+\frac{1}{x^é})))}=e^{x(log(x)+log((1+\frac{1}{x^2}))))}$$ tends to infinity. Wait for the OP reaction.

Comment: Yeah fixed the typo...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the Taylor Series for $\log(1+x)$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
x\log\left(1+\frac1x\right)
&=x\left(\frac1x-\frac1{2x^2}+O\left(\frac1{x^3}\right)\right)\\
&=1-\frac1{2x}+O\left(\frac1{x^2}\right)
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, using the Taylor Series for $e^x$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
x\left[\left(1+\frac1x\right)^x-e\right]
&=x\left[e^{1-\frac1{2x}+O\left(\frac1{x^2}\right)}-e\right]\\
&=xe\left[e^{-\frac1{2x}+O\left(\frac1{x^2}\right)}-1\right]\\
&=xe\left[-\frac1{2x}+O\left(\frac1{x^2}\right)\right]\\
&=-\frac e2+O\left(\frac1x\right)
\end{align}
$$
Thus,
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}x\left[\left(1+\frac1x\right)^x-e\right]=-\frac e2
$$

Comment: Very nice reasoning +1

Answer (score 2):

hint:$$\lim_{x\to\infty}{x\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x-e\right)}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{{\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x-e}}{\frac{1}{x}}=$$
then apply L'Hospital rule

Comment: L'Hospital seems to give something pretty complicated. Perhaps a second application with some simplification might help.